# Get user ID from their phone number

Tags: http, facebook-graph-api

How might I go about getting a users Facebook account number from their phone number? For example, I have the phone number (123)456-7891 and I would like to see if its assigned to a Facebook account, is there a certain URL that I can put in that will give me their ID?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. The graph API doesn't provide an endpoint/field for the mobile number, and the search does not support mobile numbers.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.3#search
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user#Reading